# How to test the code for the number of open connections?

Tags: go

I have a database that has a limit on open connections

```
database.SetMaxOpenConns(80)
database.SetConnMaxLifetime(170 * time.Second)
database.SetMaxIdleConns(30)
database.SetConnMaxIdleTime(100 * time.Second)
```

At some point, the number of connections exceeds the limit. Question: how best to test the code to find where the connections are consumed?

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_? (I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?)

Comment: `database/sql.DB` is implemented in a way that an active instance of it consumes no more than whatever number of connections was set using `SetMaxOpenConns`–provided that number is ≥ 1 and it was not changed to a value lower than the one set previously. So my guess would be that either you've found a bug in sql.DB, or you've found a bug in a particular DB driver you're using (say, it does not really close a connection when told to do that) or the reason is external to `sql.DB` and the driver. I would claim that the latter is the most probable issue, the second is highly unlikely, …

Comment: …and a bug in `sql.DB` is quite improbable. It's also possible that you have a bug in your own code: for instance, you can create more than a single `sql.DB` in a single process, and each of that will have its own pool of connections. Given that, I'd first inspect your code, then the activity on your DB engine–what hosts have initiated the connections? are there signs of some of them having been created by other activity like admin or backup sessions? If all this fails, you can always instrument the driver and `database/sql` code with logging and rebuild your program.